# i got error like this : DataFrame constructor not properly called

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I got error when I want to make *dataframe* after cleaning data! The code is as follows:

```
data_clean = pd.DataFrame(cleaner_data,columns=['tweet'])
data_clean.head()
```

and error info :

```
ValueError     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-1d07a4d30120> in <module>
----> 1 data_clean = pd.DataFrame(cleaner_data,columns=['tweet'])
      2 data_clean.head()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    507                 )
    508             else:
--> 509                 raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
    510 
    511         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I don't know how to solve it. It's said `dataframe constructor` no properly called.

Comment: Please can you give an example of what `cleaner_data` contains.

Comment: Also please specify what is the type of cleaner_data

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
df_clean = cleaner_data['tweet']
df_clean.head()
```